# IDA error: "write access to const memory has been detected"

Tags: ida, disassembly

I'am a newbie of IDA and after disassably a file I get this error on some subroutine:

"write access to const memory has been detected"

```
// write access to const memory has been detected, the output may be wrong!
_BYTE *__thiscall sub_49D020(_BYTE *this, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5)
{
  _BYTE *v5; // esi

  v5 = this;
  sub_45C210(a2, a3, a4, a5);
  *(_DWORD *)v5 = &off_4DE648;
  ++dword_5BB8D4;
  v5[68] = 1;
  if ( dword_5BBDD0 )
  {
    if ( dword_5BBD70 )
      sub_41CBE0();
    sub_485810(*(_DWORD *)(dword_5BBDD0 + 28));
  }
  return v5;
}




.text:0049D020 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:0049D020
.text:0049D020
.text:0049D020 sub_49D020      proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_412400+35↑p
.text:0049D020                                         ; sub_42A080+34↑p ...
.text:0049D020
.text:0049D020 var_10          = dword ptr -10h
.text:0049D020 var_C           = dword ptr -0Ch
.text:0049D020 var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:0049D020 arg_0           = dword ptr  4
.text:0049D020 arg_4           = dword ptr  8
.text:0049D020 arg_8           = dword ptr  0Ch
.text:0049D020 arg_C           = dword ptr  10h
.text:0049D020
.text:0049D020 ; FUNCTION CHUNK AT .text:004D9650 SIZE 00000008 BYTES
.text:0049D020
.text:0049D020                 push    0FFFFFFFFh
.text:0049D022                 push    offset SEH_49D020
.text:0049D027                 mov     eax, large fs:0
.text:0049D02D                 push    eax
.text:0049D02E                 mov     large fs:0, esp
.text:0049D035                 push    ecx
.text:0049D036                 mov     eax, [esp+10h+arg_C]
.text:0049D03A                 mov     edx, [esp+10h+arg_4]
.text:0049D03E                 push    esi
.text:0049D03F                 mov     esi, ecx
.text:0049D041                 mov     ecx, [esp+14h+arg_8]
.text:0049D045                 push    eax
.text:0049D046                 mov     eax, [esp+18h+arg_0]
.text:0049D04A                 push    ecx
.text:0049D04B                 push    edx
.text:0049D04C                 push    eax
.text:0049D04D                 mov     ecx, esi
.text:0049D04F                 mov     [esp+24h+var_10], esi
.text:0049D053                 call    sub_45C210
.text:0049D058                 mov     dword ptr [esi], offset off_4DE648
.text:0049D05E                 mov     ecx, dword_5BB8D4
.text:0049D064                 inc     ecx
.text:0049D065                 mov     [esp+14h+var_4], 0
.text:0049D06D                 mov     dword_5BB8D4, ecx
.text:0049D073                 mov     byte ptr [esi+44h], 1
.text:0049D077                 mov     eax, dword_5BBDD0
.text:0049D07C                 test    eax, eax
.text:0049D07E                 jz      short loc_49D09D
.text:0049D080                 mov     ecx, dword_5BBD70
.text:0049D086                 test    ecx, ecx
.text:0049D088                 jz      short loc_49D08F
.text:0049D08A                 call    sub_41CBE0
.text:0049D08F
.text:0049D08F loc_49D08F:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_49D020+68↑j
.text:0049D08F                 mov     ecx, dword_5BBDD0
.text:0049D095                 mov     ecx, [ecx+1Ch]
.text:0049D098                 call    sub_485810
.text:0049D09D
.text:0049D09D loc_49D09D:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_49D020+5E↑j
.text:0049D09D                 mov     ecx, [esp+14h+var_C]
.text:0049D0A1                 mov     eax, esi
.text:0049D0A3                 mov     large fs:0, ecx
.text:0049D0AA                 pop     esi
.text:0049D0AB                 add     esp, 10h
.text:0049D0AE                 retn    10h
.text:0049D0AE sub_49D020      endp
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: What are the addresses mentioned in Output window?

Comment: In what segment is dword_5BB8D4 situated?